# Пытаюсь запустить сервер БД, но почему не запускается сервер MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, битрикс, centos

Стоит комп именованный "сервером", на котором стоит виртуалка с запущенным окружением битрикса. после некорректного перезапуска "сервера" не запускается сервер MySQL. Память проверял, место на диске есть
Вот результаты проверки статуса работы процесса:

```
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: activating (start) since Пт 2020-12-25 10:50:24 +06; 4s ago
Docs: man:mysqld(8)
dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
Process: 3860 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Control: 3888 (mysqld)
CGroup: /system.slice/mysqld.service
├─3888 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
└─3891 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

дек 25 10:50:24 server systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
[root@server init.d]# journalctl -xe
-- Subject: Начинается запуск юнита mysqld.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Начат процесс запуска юнита mysqld.service.
дек 25 10:50:30 server mysqld[3888]: Initialization of mysqld failed: 0
дек 25 10:50:30 server systemd[1]: mysqld.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
дек 25 10:50:30 server systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
-- Subject: Ошибка юнита mysqld.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Произошел сбой юнита mysqld.service.
--
-- Результат: failed.
дек 25 10:50:30 server systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
дек 25 10:50:30 server systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
дек 25 10:50:30 server systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
дек 25 10:50:30 server systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Server.
-- Subject: Завершена остановка юнита mysqld.service.
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Процесс остановки юнита mysqld.service был завершен.
дек 25 10:50:30 server systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
-- Subject: Начинается запуск юнита mysqld.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Начат процесс запуска юнита mysqld.service.
дек 25 10:50:36 server mysqld[3953]: Initialization of mysqld failed: 0
дек 25 10:50:36 server systemd[1]: mysqld.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
дек 25 10:50:37 server systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
-- Subject: Ошибка юнита mysqld.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Произошел сбой юнита mysqld.service.
--
-- Результат: failed.
дек 25 10:50:37 server systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
дек 25 10:50:37 server systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
дек 25 10:50:37 server systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
дек 25 10:50:37 server systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Server.
-- Subject: Завершена остановка юнита mysqld.service.
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Процесс остановки юнита mysqld.service был завершен.
дек 25 10:50:37 server systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
-- Subject: Начинается запуск юнита mysqld.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Начат процесс запуска юнита mysqld.service.
дек 25 10:50:37 server sshd[3986]: Invalid user 113.53.251.125 from 142.93.169.136 port 51602
дек 25 10:50:37 server sshd[3986]: input_userauth_request: invalid user 113.53.251.125 [preauth]
дек 25 10:50:37 server sshd[3986]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
дек 25 10:50:37 server sshd[3986]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=142.93.169.136
дек 25 10:50:39 server sshd[3986]: Failed password for invalid user 113.53.251.125 from 142.93.169.136 port 51602 ssh2
дек 25 10:50:39 server sshd[3986]: Received disconnect from 142.93.169.136 port 51602:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
дек 25 10:50:39 server sshd[3986]: Disconnected from 142.93.169.136 port 51602 [preauth]

В логах задачи виртуалки битрикса указано это:
PLAY [bitrix-hosts] ************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [server]

TASK [mysql : include variables from mysql group] ******************************
ok: [server]

TASK [mysql : include variables from web group] ********************************
ok: [server]

TASK [mysql : include variables from temporary config] *************************
ok: [server]

TASK [mysql : additional gathering facts] **************************************
ok: [server]

TASK [mysql : set_fact] ********************************************************

TASK [mysql : gathering facts about installed sites] ***************************

TASK [mysql : set_fact] ********************************************************

TASK [mysql : debug] ***********************************************************

TASK [mysql : create variable bx_sites_info] ***********************************

TASK [mysql : debug] ***********************************************************

TASK [mysql : include] *********************************************************

TASK [mysql : include] *********************************************************

TASK [mysql : include] *********************************************************
included: /etc/ansible/roles/mysql/tasks/mysql-start_service.yml for server

TASK [mysql : include] *********************************************************
included: /etc/ansible/roles/mysql/tasks/mysql-enable_service.yml for server

TASK [mysql : defined bx_system variable] **************************************
ok: [server]

TASK [mysql : recreate links] **************************************************

TASK [mysql : reload systemd configuration] ************************************

TASK [mysql : start mysql service] *********************************************
fatal: [server]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Unable to start service mysqld: Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See \"systemctl $

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/mysql.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
server : ok=8 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=1
```

Сам текст исключения который возникает при попытке входа по URL сайта:

```
[Bitrix\Main\DB\ConnectionException] 
Mysql connect error [localhost]: (2002) Connection refused (400)
/home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/lib/db/mysqliconnection.php:65
#0: Bitrix\Main\DB\MysqliConnection->connectInternal()
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/lib/data/connection.php:53
#1: Bitrix\Main\Data\Connection->getResource()
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/lib/db/mysqlisqlhelper.php:21
#2: Bitrix\Main\DB\MysqliSqlHelper->forSql(string)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/lib/config/option.php:193
#3: Bitrix\Main\Config\Option::load(string)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/lib/config/option.php:38
#4: Bitrix\Main\Config\Option::get(string, string, string)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/lib/httprequest.php:394
#5: Bitrix\Main\HttpRequest->prepareCookie(array)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/lib/httprequest.php:71
#6: Bitrix\Main\HttpRequest->__construct(object, array, array, array, array)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/lib/httpapplication.php:49
#7: Bitrix\Main\HttpApplication->initializeContext(array)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/lib/application.php:131
#8: Bitrix\Main\Application->initializeExtendedKernel(array)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/include.php:24
#9: require_once(string)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php:14
#10: require_once(string)
    /home/bitrix/www/index.php:8
```

Прошу прощения за кашу во всем этом, так как в своей организации и швец и жнец. Нормального опыта в работе не имею пока

Comment: В консоле попробуйте подключиться к БД. Войти черес коммандную строку.

Comment: @doox911 Нашел в логах MySQL
```2020-12-25T05:19:35.178672Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Ignoring the redo log due to missing MLOG_CHECKPOINT between the checkpoint 389077222946 and the end 389077230270.
2020-12-25T05:19:35.178864Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2020-12-25T05:19:40.304649Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2020-12-25T05:19:40.304702Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2020-12-25T05:19:40.304713Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.```

Comment: Посмотрите ответ [тут](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163445/innodb-ignoring-the-redo-log-due-to-missing-mlog-checkpoint)